# Every sequence has a monotone sub-sequence (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, real-numbers

Since I am new to real analysis, I want to verify whether my steps are correct or not( as it would be disastrous for me to perform mistakes and be unknown to them).
Proof: Let $(a_n)$ be any arbitrary sequence. Let $S=\{a_m:\forall n>m,a_m<a_n \}$. Suppose $S$ is a finite set.  If $S=\phi$, then for all $m \in \mathbb N$,there is an $n  (> m)\in \mathbb N$ such that $a_m \geq a_n$. Let us now take $m=2$. It would follow that there is an $n_0$ such that $a_2 \geq a_{n_0}$ for $n_0>m$. Performing the above step repeatedly in similar manner by replacing $m=n_0,...$,we will get a monotonically decreasing sub-sequence of $(a_n)$. If $|S|=n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$,all we need to do is to take the sequence $(b_n)$, a sub-sequence of $(a_n)$, defined as $b_1=a_{sup S+1}$ and $b_n=a_{n+supS}$ for all $n>1$. If we create a set $S'$ same as $S$ but for $(b_n)$,we get $S'=\phi$. Now,we can do what we did before to create a monotonically decreasing sub-sequence of $(b_n)$ which in turn will be a sub-sequence of $(a_n)$.

If $S$ is infinite, then the result follows immediately by ordering the $m's$ from small to big. Hence,proved.

I tried to find an algorithmic proof to this,i.e,that sort of proof which will create a monotone sub-sequence just by checking whether two consecutive terms in the sequence maintain the monotonicity or not. For instance, check the sign of $a_2-a_1$ and check whether $a_4-a_3$ has the same sign. If yes, include it in the sub-sequence,if no drop the $a_4$ term and move to check for the next term. If someone can provide such proof,I shall be grateful.

Comment: Note that this is only true if by monotone you mean non-strict,  as a  sequence that is a constant value at all but a finite number of places  has no strictly increasing or decreasing subsequence

Comment: By the way OP, you may want to look at the standard proof to this also, which is the Lemma in the proof to Bolzano-Weierstrass: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem The lemma talks about "peaks"...